# "gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception" when invoking 'channel.sendTransactionProposal'

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Getting below gRPC error when tls is enabled and tried to send transaction proposal to peer.

Taken reference code from here: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/hyperledger-fabric-java-sdk-for-tls-enabled-fabric-network/
I have enabled TLS on all peers and on overall network. I tried by giving certificate/pem string directly also in code. But, same exception.

What I am missing here? I am running client application from Eclipse directly. 
Thank you in advance.

------------------------- Code starts ---------------

```
HFClient hfClient = HFClient.createNewInstance();
hfClient.setCryptoSuite(cryptoSuite);
hfClient.setUserContext(admin_registar);

String peer_name = "peer0.org1.example.com";
String peer_url = "grpcs://localhost:7051"; // Ensure that port is of peer1
String peerTLSCertFileName = "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt";    ***// Taking TLS certitifcate***

Properties peerProperties = new Properties();
peerProperties.setProperty("pemFile", peerCertFile.getAbsolutePath());
peerProperties.setProperty("allowAllHostNames", "true");
Path peerPath = Paths.get(peerTLSCertFileName);        ;
peerProperties.put("pemBytes", Files.readAllBytes(peerPath));
**peerProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL"); // SETTING TLS properties
peerProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");   // SETTING TLS properties**
Peer peer = hfClient.newPeer(peer_name, peer_url, peerProperties);

<< --- Similar code to add Orderer to HFClient --->>

Channel channel = hfClient.newChannel("mychannel");
channel.addPeer(peer);
channel.addOrderer(orderer);
channel.initialize();

TransactionProposalRequest request = hfClient.newTransactionProposalRequest();
String cc = "fabcar"; // Chaincode name
ChaincodeID ccid = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName(cc).build();

request.setChaincodeID(ccid);
request.setFcn("createCar"); // Chaincode invoke funtion name
String[] arguments = {"CAR11", "VgW", "Poglo", "Ggrey", "Margy"}; // Arguments that Chaincode function takes
request.setArgs(arguments);
request.setProposalWaitTime(3000);
**Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channel.sendTransactionProposal(request); // this is line throwing exception**
```

------------------------- Code ends ---------------

### Below exception is at last line of code above:

Exception in thread "main" org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com.  Status FAILURE, details: Channel Channel{id: 3, name: mychannel} Sending proposal with transaction: 353dde2899c1993b9e643ac32b7b9c27ae4eeda1aaa17bc13f1c35f91795a9f7 to Peer{ id: 1, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel, url: **grpcs://localhost:7051} failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception**
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0], cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this issue when I had not run the CreateChannel command.

java -cp blockchain-client.jar org.example.network.CreateChannel